# How to increase load voltage?

Tags: arduino, transistors, bjt

In my circuit diagram I measured +/- 0.7V across the motor. This barely moves the motor as it needs about 5-6V. The resistors in the circuit diagram are 1K.

I've tested the circuit with a low powered motor. What would be your suggestions on increasing the voltage/current across for a higher powered motor? Ideally 5-6V and 4-5A. I think it would also be useful to know that I'm using a 505 std servo from china.

Thank you!

[image]

EDIT: New cct diagram

Comment: Top transistor must be a PNP type.

Comment: Is that a reversing circuit? It does not look right.

Comment: @Harper, sorry I have the top transistors as PNPs. Thought this was my new drawing! I can confirm that it successfully reverses the motor direction.

Comment: sorry! Yes I've editted the post.

Comment: What transistors are they? What current does the motor draw? Can you measure the current being drawn from 5V?

Comment: The control signal from one pin should be tied in another way.The top left PNP transistor should be grounded and the bottom right NPN should be at 5V to spin the motor into a direction.For reverse you should tie în mirror.

Comment: What is your 5V supply? Are you sure it is able to supply enough amps to drive the motor? Have you tried hooking it up directly to the motor just to confirm? Also, please specify the types of transistors you are using. In future, to facilitate discussion, give each circuit element a unique reference designator.

Comment: @SteveG: They are 2N3906's and 2N3904's. The motor draws 100mA with a 9V supply and the current being drawn is practically nothing: 0.004A.

Comment: @mkeith: I was initially using 5V from an Arduino, but switch to a 9V battery with not much change. With the 5V/9V supply directly connected to the motor it works as intended. Sorry about the terrible post structure.

Comment: @StefanMerfu: Thank you for your prompt response. I've been able to successfully reverse the motor direction, but I switched out the motor so the load needs to be increased. I'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: If you're measuring 0.7 volts it sounds like you're measuring the volt drop of a transistor

Comment: You've driven either the top or the bottom transistors into saturation by applying the wrong voltage, so the other is switched off and the only voltage present is the Vbe.

Comment: If you changed the motor supply to 9 V, then the Arduino (outputing 5 V) was not able to turn the PNP transistors off. This could have caused current backflow to the Arduino (depending on your base resistor values) damaging it, or high current flow through the BJT's damaging them. Double check your Arduino is still producing 0 V for low and 5 V for high, throw away your BJTs and replace them, and try again. If you want to use 9 V for the motor voltage, add an open-collector BJT stage to buffer the Arduino from the 9 V (you'll find lots of diagrams of this configuration around).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange answers you sometimes get at this place. Why discuss 9V, if your drawing clearly shows 5V?

Anyway. The circuit seems fine, under a certain set of assumptions, however some of which seem to be violated. If your power supply is strong enough, then either the transistors are not driven into saturation, or their hFE is not high enough (arguably the same thing).

Assuming you drive the circuit with 0V or 5V, respectively, i.e. digital "CMOS" signals. If you don't, for instance you use 3.3V signals, then the PNPs never shut off completely! So make sure you use 5V signals.

With such signals, base current will be either 0mA or (5V-0.7V)/1000Ohms=4.3mA.
In order to drive 4-5A, you'll need a beta (or hFE) of 1000, which few transistors achieve. Without a fundamental change to the circuit, you have three options:
a) reduce the base resistors such that more base current can flow (make sure the signal source can deliver the current). b) change the transistors to Darlington types (careful with increased BE voltage). c) use MOSFETs (typically, such a so-called H-bridge configuration is built with MOSFETs nowadays).

Since in some reply you mentioned 2N3904, there may be another problem: This transistor is specified to drive 200mA maximum. Didn't you mention 4-5A ? You say you tested a low-powered motor, which may only need 200mA. You should know. The 2N3904's maximum hFE is 300, BTW.

The advice to make sure you use 5V signals is valid of course only if your power supply is 5V. For this kind of circuit make sure they match.

Note option c is suitable only if you only switch the motor on/off and reverse it - if you want to use PWM to control speed you will want n-channel FETs in all four places which makes the circuit much more complicated.

Answer (score 12):

Stop and take a deep breath. You seem to have gone through a number of changes to your circuit, and it's hard to tell exactly what you've ended up with. Let's assume that you currently have

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fybi6z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now. First things first. Get yourself a cheap DMM. No argurments, no backtalk, just do it. Without one you really have no way to tell what's happening in your circuit.

Next, get rid of your 9 volt battery. Again, no backtalk. Switch back to your 5 volt supply. The problem is that, with a 9 volt supply, both Q1 and Q3 will be at least partly turned on, no matter what the state of the control inputs. This means that when you turn on either NPN that side will be shorted to ground, and your battery voltage will drop very badly.

I recommend putting an LED and a 1k resistor from 5 volts to ground, just to help you see if the power supply is getting overloaded. If it dims, you know something is pulling down the battery. And if something is pulling down your battery, now that you have a DMM you can figure out what it is, rather than guessing.

If you want to try your 9 volt battery, you need to buffer your inputs so as to drive them to 9 volts when high. You can do this (for one half of the circuit, by

[image: schematic]

But if you try this make sure you replace both halves of the circuit. I only showed one side - the other should be identical.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, OK! I got a DMM and also put in a 1K resistor and an LED and it lights up bright with no dimming happening. So the 5V supply is not being overloaded. What I do notice is the 2N3904's are getting pretty warm and have: 

2.6V - 3.8V across Q4 and 
2.8V - 3.2V across Q2

alternating back and forth between the two. These voltages are measured across the collector and emitters of the transistors

EDIT: They voltages across the 1K resistors are all 3.4V and the motor is moving slight back and forth.

Comment: OK. First, you need to look at the Arduino outputs. Are they stable, or are they alternating on and off? If they are alternating, modify your software so one is high and one is low. Try replacing the 2N3904 base resistors (R2 and R4) with 500 ohm resistors. The reason your NPNs are getting hot is that they are not turning on completely, and more base current will help. But also check that the Arduino voltages don't get pulled down too much. 2N3904s should be able to drive 100 mA with a drop of less than 0.5 volts, but that may take ~10 mA of base drive.

Comment: And while I'm at it, please check the high voltage at the Arduino outputs while under load. The PNP drive assumes that the high voltage will go near 5 volts in order to turn off the PNPs. If you're getting 4 volts at the control inputs you're mostly OK, but at 3.4 you're drawing more current, and that's part of the reason why the NPNs are struggling.